# VCS: push only source code directory

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I work on Java project. How I can push only source directory without temporary files, build files and project files? I use Mercurial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial will only push **history**, which means that it is only things that you have asked it to track (with `hg add`) and later committed (with `hg commit`) that will be pushed.

So like Jim says, you should setup [`.hgignore`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) file. Do this before adding files to your project and double-check that `hg status` only lists files you want to add. Then run `hg add` to add them all.

If you've already put the temporary files and build artifacts under version control, then you can either use `hg forget` to stop tracking them. You'll still carry them around in the history, so if we've talking about tens of megabytes, then you probably want to re-create the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Create an [.hgignore](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) file.